# How do I hide <TR> tags that don't contain any text using CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> CELL_1 </td>
        <td> CELL_2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> GOOD_CELL_1 </td>
        <td> BAD_CELL_2 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Say I have an input field.

When I type there - I want those `<TR>`'s that DON'T have the typed string to go away (disappear, become hidden etc.).

I started it like this:

```
$('#searchinput').keypress(function() {

});
```

How do I finish this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#searchinput').keypress(function() {
    $('table tr').show().not(':contains(' + this.value + ')').hide();
});
```

Comment: OP was asking for hiding tds, not trs.  Otherwise good (through that bit might get a bit tricky for formatting reasons)